# How to access oplog database on MongoDB on compose (IBM Cloud)

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, compose-db

i am trying to setup a HA instance of rocket chat on IBM Cloud (Bluemix).
My application nodes are running on Cloud Foundry while I use for the database MongoDB on compose.

I followed this guide:
https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/docker-containers/high-availability-install/

but my application crashes on startup when I am providing the env-var for the oplog db. So my question:
Is there any support for oplog on Mongo on Compose at all?
If yes, how to access the database?

Best
Patrick

UPDATE:
As asked by @kylemclaren here the error logs:

```
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR
> /app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313   
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR                      throw(ex);   
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR                      ^   
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR MongoError: no
> primary found in replicaset or invalid replica set name   
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> /app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:560:28
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> Server.<anonymous>
> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:312:24)
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)    2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200
> [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)   
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Server.emit
> (events.js:211:7)    2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 
> at
> /app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:300:14
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> /app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
> 2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)    2018-08-07T21:03:29.62+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
> process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add oplog support to Compose.io by paying an additional fee.

By logging into your compose.io database you can navigate to the addons section and activate it there.

[image: Addon Menu Screenshot]

Comment: Hello treve, please read my posting carefully. I am using compose on IBM Cloud so that information does not help at all. I know that with a plain compose deployment the option exists, but that's exactly why I was asking if the option exists on IBM Cloud ;)